# Swift, how to encrypt backend communications?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, encryption

I have an app. One of my users sent me an email warning me that my app was "POSTing in plaintext." If you hook it up to a mac and observe the console, you can see the user's data communicating with my server in plaintext, and the API key.

The first thing I did was change the URL of my server to https:// (there is a valid SSL on there, and accessing via https:// is successful) thinking that would automatically encrypt everything, but I'm missing something because everything is still appearing in plaintext.

Total noobie question, but I'm lost here.

What do I do to make my iOS app (programmed in Swift and Objective-C, with core parts in Objective-C) communicating with a CentOS server running Rails have encrypted communications?

Comment: Using HTTPS is enough. The request is in plaintext in the console because you're seeing it *before* it gets encrypted. After that, it's fully encrypted.

Comment: Thank you, that is great news to hear! I appreciate the reply. Is there any 3rd party way I can test the encryption and see encrypted data transferring (just the chars, or whatever is visible) so I can be 100% positive?

Comment: Use Wireshark.  Manually send an HTTP request to your server while Wireshark is running and you'll see it pop up under TLSv1.2 in Wireshark.  It will just look like pseudo-randomness.